# How to change the config file location of a virtual directory?

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

I need to publish my web application like below

1.root application(http://test.smt.com)

2.virtual directory(http://test.smt.com/console)

my root application contains virtual dir

```
Root

  Folder 1(with 1.config)
  Folder 2(with 2.config)
  Folder 3(with 3.config)
  Folder 4(with 4.config) // I've created this directory as virtual dir

root.config
```

Now the issue i'm getting is "Parser error"
I know that Root application access root.config also the virtual dir access 4.config

can we change the virtual directory to access its root.config only not 4.config?

Comment: I am not sure if I follow you but you can change the web.config file using XPAth I have done this several times on a project. you may also want to store the location of the other directories inside of that web.config just a thought.. I will search for my example I did about 2 years ago

Comment: Thanks @DJKRAZE.. i'm looking for your reply...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found a soln
need not to create a separate virtual dir in IIS.
I just entered http://test.smt.com/Folder4 (Folder 4 which is named as console dir)
it works for me... i'm happy....